# Reactjs fade div with inline styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add a **fade-in** animation to `<div>fading-in text</div>` using only **inline styles**?

```
class Practise extends Component {
  state = { show: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.show) return <div>default regular text</div>;
    return <div>fading-in text</div>;
  }
}
```

*(No library solutions please, I want to figure it out natively)*

Comment: I think this solution answers this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947729/reactjs-set-transition-in-inline-css

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `setState` method has a callback as second(optional) parameter. So once you set your `this.state.show` to `true` you can increment your `opacity` using this callback parameter. The callback function may look like below:

```
fadingIn(){
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.state.opacity === 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    this.setState({ opacity: this.state.opacity + 0.1 })
  }, 100);
}
```

So as you already added `componentDidMount` you can trigger it there

```
componentDidMount(){
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({ show: true }, this.fadingIn), 1000)
}

render(){
  return <div>
      {!this.state.show
        ? <div>Regular</div>
        : <div style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}}>Fade In</div>}
     </div>
  }
```

[`Worked Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98975/)

***UPDATE***

Try something like this:

```
const withFading = ({ Faded, duration, isOut }) => {
  const inEffect = `
    @keyframes react-fade-in {
      0%   { opacity: 0; }
      50%  { opacity: 0; }
      100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
  `;

  const outEffect = `
    @keyframes react-fade-out {
      0%   { opacity: 1; }
      50%  { opacity: 0; }
      100% { opacity: 0; }
    }
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      // Here we add style tag with the css for fadeIn & fadeOut 
      // depends on a input value of isOut parameter.
      // It does same thing as an example from below 
      // <style>
      //   body { your css rules }
      // </style>
      // with react we can pass `body { ... }` as a child into
      // style tag as i did.
      <style children={isOut ? outEffect : inEffect} />
        <div style={{
          animationDuration: `${duration}s`,
          animationIterationCount: 1,
          animationName: `react-fade-${(isOut ? 'out' : 'in')}`,
          animationTimingFunction: isOut ? 'ease-out' : 'ease-in'
          }}
        ><Faded /></div>
    </div>
  ) 

}

const Hello = () => <div>Hello</div>
const FadedHello = withFading({ Faded: Hello, duration: 2, isOut: false});
```

[`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98985/)

Comment: Thanks, any way to do it without setTimeout or setInterval? Seems hacky and is also affected by blocking code

Comment: I want to do it only using inline styles. The `react-transition-group` package does it without any classNames but I can't figure out how it does do it

Comment: @WooQuee i'm not sure about `react-transition-group` & inline styles. Actually they are using classes for `active/enter/etc` actions. Take a look at [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/CSSTransition.js). Anyway i updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, can you add some description to describe what the code is doing? I don't understand what this is `<style children={isOut ? outEffect : inEffect} />`

Comment: @WooQuee It's add `style` tag with inserted css into it. Same as `<style> ...</style>` Where dots is css rules

Comment: So this `children` prop is some sort of a reserved prop on the style element?

Comment: and can this be done using `opacity` and `transition` instead of keyFrames since their browser support is a lot worse?

Comment: @WooQuee Go ahead and try

Comment: That's what I've been trying to use since I've asked the question, but just can't figure it out

Comment: @WooQuee no idea how do you want to have fadeIn effect without using css classes & setInterval. Let me know if you find something that your are looking for

Comment: I achieve it using this library `https://github.com/felipethome/react-inline-transition-group` but I don't know how it works, could have a look at it please so see what makes it work ?

Comment: @TheReason Dude! That style tag is wicked!! Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 6):

I try to answer your question in the "The Reason's" comment section (this question: can this be done using opacity and transition instead of keyFrames...")
As far as I know, we have to use add a trigger for the transition (such as hover pseudo-class in CSS or onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave props in react events)

Here is my answer and I have tested it

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: isHovered ? 'orange' : 'green',
        opacity: isHovered ? 1 : 0,
        height: isHovered ? 400 : 200,
        width: isHovered ? 400 : 200,
        transition: 'all 1s',
      }}
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
    >
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. CSS animations are the simplest way to add animations to elements IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You have changed show from false to true after particular time which will not give effect of fade in fade out.

Instead you have to `change opacity 1 to 0` after some fix seconds. And when opacity is `0`. You can set `show: true`

Check this link 
https://jsfiddle.net/kaushikbarodiya/La3wysxk/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but code in your link doesn't produce a 'fade-in' animation

Comment: But did you got idea what I am trying to do?

Comment: No because it doesn't do what I'm looking for